# Too much recursion error on jQuery datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I using jQuery DateTimePicker v2.4.3 with jQuery v1.11.2, and Firefox v56.0 (32).

Here is the INPUT definition:

```
<input id="dlp2" name="param2" class="form-control input-sm" maxlength="16" size="16" value="2021.10.05 18:00" readonly="" type="text">
```

And the initialization:

```
$('#dlp2').datetimepicker({
    datepicker: true,
    timepicker: true,
    value: maiValue,
    lang: 'hu',
    closeOnDateSelect: true,
    weeks: true,
    defaultDate: maiNap,
    defaultTime: maiIdo,
    dayOfWeekStart: 1,
    format: 'Y.m.d HH:mm',
    todayButton: true,
    inline: false,
    onSelectDate: function (ct, $i) {
        // $('#datepickerig').val($('#datepickertol').val());
    }
});
```

Where is the

- maiValue is "2021.10.05",
- maiNap is "2021.10.05" and
- maiIdo is "18:00".

When the Firefox's Javascript is running this initialization, then throw an too much recursion error on jquery.datetimepicker.js:7:15

When the Chrome's (v92.0.4515.159 (64 bit) Javascript is running, then thow an error: attached on picture.

[image]

What is wrong?

Please, help me, if possible!

Comment: The maiValue really value is "2021.10.05 18:00", of course.
Sorry!

Comment: edit the question instead of commenting a correction?